# Token from INamedTypeSymbol

Tags: roslyn

Given a `INamedTypeSymbol` object, and the need to translate it to a `Token` that represents a literal usage of the type (e.g. translate `typeof(bool)`'s `INamedTypeSymbol` to a `Token` for `bool`),

- Does that `INamedTypeSymbol` map to *one* or *several* possible corresponding `SyntaxToken`(s) depending on the intended usage of the token?
- How would one derive the corresponding `SyntaxToken`(s)?

Comment: Do you mean for primitive types only?

Comment: Good question! Despite my example using `bool`, I mean either primitive or non-primitive. If it depends on whether or not the `INamedTypeSymbol`'s type is primitive, then a complete answer would need to show both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a `SyntaxGenerator` for your language from the workspace's (/ project's) language services, then call `SyntaxGenerator.TypeExpression(symbol)`.

Comment: `SyntaxGenerator` is not available in my case, and I'm having a hard time finding any documentation on where to acquire it. I'm using `CodeGeneration.Roslyn` from nuget.

Comment: @M-Pixel: You can get it from a document or project.  http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Editing/SyntaxGenerator.cs,50

Comment: @m_Pixel you will need the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces package.

Comment: Alright, we're getting there. `CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces` did indeed give me `SyntaxGenerator`. `SyntaxGenerator` then requires either a `Document`, `Project`, or `Workspace`. I have `MemberDeclarationSyntax` `SemanticModel`, and `CSharpCompilation` - can any of the three `SyntaxGenerator` requirements be derived from any of the three types that I have access to?

Comment: @M-Pixel: All SyntaxNodes should have a `Document` property.

Comment: Workspaces and types like Document are part of an object model that is built on top of the compiler API.  So SyntaxNodes do not know anything about workspaces.  However, the truth is it does not matter which workspace you use to construct the syntax generator.  It is just using the workspace to find the internal language services that know about CSharp and VB.  So you can just create an empty instance of AdHocWorkspace and use that.